# Where to find the setting to change side switch functionality in iOS 10 Beta?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, sound-volume

Can't find the setting to change the side switch functionality from 'Ringer/Silent' to 'Mute/Orientation lock'.

If this functionality has been removed, is there any way to use the side switch to mute my app sound?

Comment: This feature is only available on iPad (you can't switch it on iPhone, mute is too important). It should be right where it was before, in Settings -> General as per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204171

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 6S & an iPad Air, both running iOS 10 Beta. There is no option to change the side switch setting in general.

Comment: Not sure what to say then, sorry. Wait until iOS 10 comes out, I guess.